# Combine ax and fig from two user-defined functions into a single plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have two different functions, each of which produces a plot. I'm wondering how to do if I want to combine both in a single plot, e.g. `plt.subplots(nrow=2,ncol=1)`

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")


def function1():
    uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
    ff=sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax);
    return(fig,ax)

def function2():
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
    sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ax=ax)
    return(fig,ax)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [recommended way (from the official doc)](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#coding-styles) is to pass a reference to your Axes to your plotting function

```
import seaborn as sns

def function1(ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
    ff=sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax);


def function2(ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
    sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ax=ax)


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrow=2,ncol=1)
function1(ax=ax1)
function2(ax=ax2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could be indexing your axes `ax` to plot each `seaborn` plot.

This could be done with something like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

def function1(ax):
    uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
    ff=sns.heatmap(uniform_data, ax=ax);

def function2(ax):
    sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, ax=ax)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

function1(ax[0])
function2(ax[1])

plt.show()
```